# Raspberry pi fails to boot from USB after cloning disk (HomeAssistant)

Tags: raspberry-pi, dd

My SSD I was running HomeAssistant on was getting a bit to small so I got a larger disk.

I cloned my disk via:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sde bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

(where indeed sdc was my old disk and sde my new disk)

However my raspberry pi does not want to boot with this new disk attached. At first I thought it might be an issue with the resize but even if I leave it all as-is it does not want to boot.

Gparted cloned disk:

[image: Gparted cloned disk]

Gparted original disk:

[image: Gparted original disk]

I tried attaching a monitor to the PI but I don't get any output leaving me to assume it does not even want to boot. The power LED is on, the activity let is solid yellow.

Any ideas what to do? I can still boot from the original disk.

Comment: Did you try the Raspberry PI Imager for this. Part of Pi 5 for sure and I think Pi 4 as well. This is a better way to make a new SD card.

Comment: @John, no I did not, in this case I don't want a new image I want to clone my install to a new (bigger) disk. I think the rpi-imager can write custom img files but as `dd` already makes a bit-for-bit copy I don't see why that should work. I can try it this evening though.

Comment: For me that did not have any other effect (sorry for the late reply).